# Why does [[]][0]++ work but []++ throws run-time exception?

Tags: javascript

Why does the first line work while the second line throws `run-time exception`?

The first line:

```
[[]][0]++; //this line works fine
```

The second line:

```
[]++; //this lines throws exception
```

Comment: Yeah, I think a lot of people read Dave's blog:
https://davidwalsh.name/thinking-javascript

Comment: Because Javascript.

Comment: Why would you expect otherwise? Can you explain why the first line should throw an exception, or what the second line should do when it would not?

Comment: @Bergi They both appear to do the same thing: Increment an empty array. They just do it differently. I would expect them both to throw, as incrementing an array is nonsense

Comment: @Suppen But `[…][…]` is not an empty array, it's a property access. That the property contains an empty array doesn't matter here. The difference is like between `var x = []; x++` and `[]++` - you can increment a variable, but not a literal.

Comment: That's how it actually works, as described by the accepted answer. They just appear to do the exact same thing in different ways

Comment: What bothers me more is the `0` literal... if you're going through the trouble of using obscure JavaScript, you should at least use `+[]` instead. :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
[[]][0]++
```

is equivalent to

```
var tmp = [[]];
tmp[0] = tmp[0]+1;
```

`tmp[0]` is an empty array, which is cast to the number `0`, which increments to `1`.

This only works because `<array>[<index>]++` *looks* valid. It takes some type juggling, but it gets there.

But `[]++` is outright invalid. There's no way to make it make sense.

```
[] = []+1;
```

The left-hand side here is indeed invalid. You can't assign to an empty array.

Comment: This also works with `[''][0]++` and `[null][0]++` and `[false][0]++` because they all cast to `0`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It has nothing to do with "looking" valid. It's just that the `++` operator requires a reference, which `[]` (a literal) is not.

Comment: "You can't assign to an emty array"... indeed now as 2021 you can; `[] = [];` is a valid empty destructuring assignment  of zero expressions to zero variables :-)

Answer (score 11):

The `++` operator (or indeed any postfix operator) requires the operand to be a "reference" - that is, a value that can be assigned to. `[]` is a literal, so you can't assign to it. `[[]][0]` is a valid reference to an element of a temporary array.

```
0++; // not valid, `0` is a literal.
var a = [];
a++; // ok, `a` is assignable
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a rare case in which Javascript does something that actually makes sense. Consider

```
x[3]++; // Valid
3++;    // Not valid
```

If this make sense for you, then what is surprising about

```
[[]][0]++; // valid
[]++;      // not valid
```

`<array>[index]` is "a place" that you can assign or increment. That's all. The fact that you can increment `a[<expr>]` doesn't imply that you can increment `<expr>`.

The absurd part is that you can use `[]` as an index, that has the meaning of converting the array to an empty string `""` and then to the number `0`, but this is the well known problem of absurd implicit conversions of Javascript. Those implicit conversion rules are a big wart of Javascript and for example imply that `1 == [1]` or that both `[]==false` and `(![])==false`.

Javascript is pure nonsense in a lot of places... but not really here.